# Windows: check differences between two folders and copy different files in another folder

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm looking for a way to compare contents of two folders on Windows 10 and save in a third folder all files which exists in the first folder but not in the second folder.

I'm currently using Total Commander to synchronize two folders but it does not allow to specify a third folder in which I need to copy missing files.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: What should happen if both folders ("A" and "B") have one or more files with the same filename but the file content is different, i.e. different hash.  Should the file(s) in "A" be copied to "C" in this case?  I suppose define "different" to get exactly what you're after as Powershell using the `Compare-Object` might be the easiest option here.  Maybe Google for Powershell Compare-object directories.

Comment: No, different files should not be copied, only missing ones. I am about to write a PowerShell script for this, but I’m wondering if there is some GUI to make this just to let me show the thing to the user.

Comment: Well you can use WFP/XAML to give PS a UI. Have a search for `powershell xaml wpf`